# savon-multipart - How to obtain attachments

Tags: ruby, savon

I am using savon-multipart https://github.com/savonrb/savon-multipart to request a SOAP multipart response with an attachment (PDF). So far, this is my code:

```
require "savon-multipart"

client = Savon.client(
   wsdl: "http://something.de?wsdl",
   wsse_auth: [username: "uu", password: "??"]
)

reponse = client.call(:get_report, message: {
    pdfId: 1
})

response.attachments
```

Authentication works fine. I can also fetch the XML-reponse. What I can't do is extract the attachment. There does not seem to exist a method for it.

According to savon-multipart's documentation

```
response.attachments
```

should contain the attachment(s). Unfortunately ruby tells me that this method is not defined.

I could't find an example implementation of savon-multipart so I'm coming to you guys :) Hope you can help me.

Comment: Make sure you construct a multipart response. Tests are always a [good example](https://github.com/savonrb/savon-multipart/blob/150a860fdcb8bb1c844eca4f8b07ea829ca52408/spec/savon/soap/response_spec.rb#L19) on how to use the library.

Comment: What is the class of the object returned by the client.call ? May not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same problem in some code.  I hope this saves someone else some time in finding the solution.

When using savon-multipart, we had to add **multipart: true** to the parameters in call.  When that parameter was added the response returned was of type Savon::Multipart::Response which has the attachments and parts methods.

```
reponse = client.call(:get_report, message: {
    pdfId: 1
}, multipart: true)
```

Without that parameter, or with it set to false, the returned response is a Savon::Response object which does not have those methods.

Comment: This doesn't work. ```NoMethodError: undefined method `multipart' for #<Savon::LocalOptions:0x007ff50f6bfda8>```